# How to generate N FlowFiles and set the content of each FlowFile according to the data in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi, elasticsearch-5

In Elasticsearch I have this index and mapping:

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "myentries": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      }, 
      "properties": {
          "yid": {"type": "keyword"},
          "days": { 
              "properties": {
                        "Type1":  { "type": "date" },
                        "Type2":  { "type": "date" }
              }
            },
            "directions": { 
              "properties": {
                      "name": {"type": "keyword"},
                      "recorder":  { "type": "keyword" },
                      "direction":  { "type": "integer" }
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to generate N FlowFiles, 1 for each combination of values of `recorder` and `direction` in the mapping `directions`. How can I do it in Nifi? I was thinking to use `GenerateFlowFile`, but how can I apply this logic related to Elasticsearch?

One possible workaround might be to generate N FlowFiles using `GenerateFlowFile`, where `Batch` field could be hardcoded and set to 10 (the number of entries in Elastic). But then I don't know what should be the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenerateFlowFile` is probably not the right tool here, as it doesn't accept incoming connections, so you would not be able to parameterize it with the count. You can use [`SplitJson`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html), which will split the flowfile into multiple flowfiles given a *JSONPath* expression that returns an array from the JSON content.

**Update**

Here is a [great tool](http://jsonpath.com/) you can use to evaluate JSONPath dynamically and see what it matches. In your example, let's say you received data like the following:

```
{
  "yid": "nifi",
  "days" : [{"Type1": "09/07/2017"},{"Type2":"10/07/2017"}],
  "directions": [
    {
        "name": "San Francisco",
      "recorder"  : "Samsung",
      "direction": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Santa Monica",
      "recorder"  : "iPhone",
      "direction": "270"
    },
    {
        "name": "San Diego",
      "recorder"  : "Razr",
      "direction": "180"
    },
    {
        "name": "Santa Clara",
      "recorder"  : "Android",
      "direction": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSONPath expression `$.directions[*].direction` would return:

```
[
  "0",
  "270",
  "180",
  "0"
]
```

This would allow `SplitJson` to create four flowfiles with the derived content and `fragment` attributes to correlate them back to the original flowfile.

If you actually need to perform permutation logic on the resulting direction & recorder values, you may want to use `ExecuteScript` with a simple Groovy/Ruby/Python script to do that operation inline and split out the resulting values.

Comment: thanks. could you please give an example of a JSONPath expression?

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't need to perform any permutation logic. Indeed all required combinations of `direction` and `recorder` are already stored in Ellasticsearch. So, for your example, I would need to get `[
  ["Samsung", "0"],
  ["iPhone","270"],
  ["Razr","180"],
  ["Android","0"]
]`, not only `direction`. These would be 4 different FlowFiles. Is it possible to adjust `$.directions[*].direction` in order to obtain both `direction` and `recorder`?

Comment: Yes, just remove the last element of that expression -- `$.directions[*]`. The `$` is *root*, the `directions` is the *directions* element, and `[*]` means *iterate over every array element*.